# Where in the Edda does it counsel or complain against drunkenness?

Tags: scandinavian-languages

I recall reading that the Edda - either the poetic or prose Edda - counselled or complained against drunkenness.

What did it exactly say? And who said it?

Answer (score 3):

The  [Hávamál](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%A1vam%C3%A1l) ("The High One's [=Odin's] Lay") in this 1908 translation edition of the [*Elder Edda*](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/14726/14726-h/14726-h.htm) has these bits of advice and reminiscence, which might be what you are after.

> 10. A better burthen no man bears on the way than much good sense; that is thought better than riches in a strange place; such is the recourse of the indigent.
> 11. A worse provision on the way he cannot carry than too much beer-bibbing; so good is not, as it is said, beer for the sons of men.
> 12. A worse provision no man can take from table than too much beer-bibbing: for the more he drinks the less control he has of his own mind.
> 13. Oblivion's heron 'tis called that over potations hovers; he steals the minds of men. With this bird's pinions I was fettered in Gunnlods dwelling.
> 14. Drunk I was, I was over-drunk, at that cunning Fialar's. It's the best drunkenness, when every one after it regains his reason.

...

> 19. Let a man hold the cup, yet of the mead drink moderately, speak sensibly or be silent. As of a fault no man will admonish thee, if thou goest betimes to sleep.